# Function L_H in YellowPaper

Tags: yellow-paper, block-header

[image: Function L_H]

What's the difference between a Block header H and the header after it has been passed to function L_H?

L_H is defined in Section 4.4.3 Equation 32 and is used in Section 4.4.2 Equation 29(2nd)

[Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a link to the relevant part in yellow paper please.

Comment: @goodvibration It is defined in Section 4.4.3 Equation 32 and is used in Section 4.4.2 Equation 29(2nd).

Comment: Add a link to the relevant part in yellow paper please.

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, don't know how I can provide an internal link for a pdf section.

Comment: Just a link, and then a verbal specification where to go in the document (which you have already provided, just do that in the question please).